# What's the issue with this WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

What's the issue with this WPF binding

```
<TextBox Name="TagNumberTextBox" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" 
Width="200" CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="{Binding Tags, Path=[0]}"/>
```

I am getting error on `Text="{Binding Tags, Path=[0]}"`

> The property 'Path' is set more than once.

However I am expecting that this issue could be because of WCF service binding. My WCF Service is not being invoked.

WPF Screen has a DataContext which has one of the property `Tags` which is an Observable collection. I am trying to bind it to first element of that collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a binding of this form `{Binding Foo}`, the `Foo` component is the property path. It is a shorthand form where you can omit the `Path=` component.

Therefore `{Binding Tags, Path=[0]}` is setting the path to both `Tags` and `[0]`.

I suspect you are wanting to do this `{Binding Path=Tags[0]}` - or in the shorthand form `{Binding Tags[0]}`

Comment: I think the shorthand version works only for property names. Any expression like `Tags[0]`/`Tags.First`/`Tags.Something` usually ends up with some kind of error. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: as long as First or Something are public Properties  - it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `Text="{Binding Path=Tags[0]}"`.